# What causes this undefined reference in GCC 4.8?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

Recently, one of my contributors set up a CI workflow in Actions on Github for my header-only library. The CI contains of some items:

- Configure (install) (using `cmake -S . -B build/install -D CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD:STRING=11 -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=build/prefix`
- Build (install) (using `cmake --build build/install -j 3`)
- Install (using `cmake --install build/install`)
- Configure tests (using `cmake -S tests -B build/tests -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -D CPP-LAZY_CATCH_VERSION:STRING=2.12.2 -D TEST_INSTALLED_VERSION:BOOL=YES -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=build/prefix`)
- Build tests (using `cmake --build build/tests -j 3`)

My library depends on one dependency, which is `{fmt}`. `{fmt}` has an option to build shared libraries but that is not enabled (default). The CMakeFile.txt for the import of the `{fmt}` library is the following:

```
...
option(CPP-LAZY_USE_INSTALLED_FMT "Import {fmt} using find_package" NO)
if(CPP-LAZY_USE_INSTALLED_FMT)
    find_package(fmt 7 REQUIRED CONFIG)
else()
    set(FMT_INSTALL YES CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
    set(FMT_OS YES CACHE INTERNAL "")
    include(FetchContent)
    FetchContent_Declare(fmt
            GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt.git
            GIT_TAG 7e56b6b6cb021a3b4fc1310e53fac76069410840
            UPDATE_DISCONNECTED YES)
    FetchContent_MakeAvailable(fmt)
endif()

add_libray(cpp-lazy INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(cpp-lazy INTERFACE fmt::fmt)
```

However, when creating the executable to run certain tests for my library, during the linking phase on the CI on GCC 4.8, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/runner/work/cpp-lazy/cpp-lazy/build/prefix/lib/libfmt.a(format.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `_ZTVN3fmt2v712format_errorE' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
```

It suggests that I should pass the `-fPIC` flag, even though we have a static linked `{fmt}` library (note the `libfmt.a` extension). The CI step Configure (install) argument then becomes: `cmake -S . -B build/install -D CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD:STRING=17 -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=build/prefix -D "CMAKE_PROJECT_FMT_INCLUDE_BEFORE=$(pwd)/cmake/fmtPICFix.cmake"`. But that gives me:

```
CMakeFiles/LazyTests.dir/function-tools-tests.cpp.o: In function `____C_A_T_C_H____T_E_S_T____0()':
function-tools-tests.cpp:(.text+0x1afd): undefined reference to `fmt::v7::detail::vformat[abi:cxx11](fmt::v7::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v7::format_args)'
function-tools-tests.cpp:(.text+0x5b15): undefined reference to `fmt::v7::detail::vformat[abi:cxx11](fmt::v7::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v7::format_args)'
function-tools-tests.cpp:(.text+0x5e03): undefined reference to `fmt::v7::detail::vformat[abi:cxx11](fmt::v7::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v7::format_args)'
function-tools-tests.cpp:(.text+0x6039): undefined reference to `fmt::v7::detail::vformat[abi:cxx11](fmt::v7::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v7::format_args)'
function-tools-tests.cpp:(.text+0x6262): undefined reference to `fmt::v7::detail::vformat[abi:cxx11](fmt::v7::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v7::format_args)'
CMakeFiles/LazyTests.dir/join-tests.cpp.o:join-tests.cpp:(.text+0xb132): more undefined references to `fmt::v7::detail::vformat[abi:cxx11](fmt::v7::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v7::format_args)' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Furthermore, the content of `fmtPICFix.cmake` is as follows:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC")
```

This only happens in GCC 4.8 (with CI environment: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS). GCC 5 has no problems whatsoever. Further, when I compile this locally on my Windows 10 PC with GCC 4.8, no linking errors occur, which is even stranger. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: What is the thing that the linker is trying to create? Is it a shared library, or an executable?

Comment: @user253751 It's an executable. The executable performs tests of my library, which depends on libfmt.

Comment: Is your library static or shared?

Comment: @user253751 My library is a header only library.

Comment: Is your executable getting built with -fPIE?

Comment: @user253751 Yes and no. If I'm _not_ building the library with `-fPIE` the linker error is `/usr/bin/ld: /home/runner/work/cpp-lazy/cpp-lazy/build/prefix/lib/libfmt.a(format.cc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol _ZTVN3fmt2v712format_errorE' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC` (in GCC 4.8 only), so when I add the `-fPIE` flag, the error is `undefined reference to 'fmt::v7::detail::vformat[abi:cxx11](fmt::v7::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v7::format_args)'`. But `-fPIE` is only used when linking shared libs, which is not the case (as you can see at the `.a`)

Comment: Executables can also be PIE

Comment: The fmt library is only header-only when you specify that you want the header-only version.  https://fmt.dev/7.1.3/usage.html#usage-with-cmake so you use the interface `fmt::fmt-header-only` in `target_link_libraries`